# What was the name of that interactive jQuery wizard plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

a few weeks or months ago a (I think jQuery plugin) wizard was released,
which allows you to do interactive "tutorials".
You were able to create interactive boxes which relates to html elements and you were able to change to color of these boxes to red.
It's also possible that it was "just" a javascript script and not a jquery plugin.

Edit:
I know that there was a delicious bookmark button at the bottom of the site.

Edit:
It was something like that: http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/stepbystep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: http://amberjack2.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Formwizard](http://thecodemine.org/)?