# Wizard in asp.net, client vs serverside

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wizard

Im going to make a wizard in asp.net. Step one will be about 7 radiobuttons, leading to different steps. Each step will have some dropdown lists or similar, leading to a final page. The final page will be the same no matter which "route" you take. What i would like to know is: Do i solve this by creating an asp:wizard, or maybe just show/hide some asp:placeholders? Or do i make the steps on the clientside, using a generic handler to save to my database, generate json results to populate dropdowns etc? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have know-how of `jQuery` and other stuff then you must to use `jQuery/jQuery` plugins.

Wizard plugins

1. http://thecodemine.org/
2. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909401/what-was-the-name-of-that-interactive-jquery-wizard-plugin) Thread

Comment: Ok, so whats the advantage over server-side controls?

Comment: @Johan - Asynchronous operations :) No extra postback.

Comment: Yea, gotta love it :) Do you have any recommendations on specific plugins? I should mention that its an ie7 web app

Comment: Making a client-side wizard will make it great and quick from a user perspective, but bear in mind you then are *requiring* your users to have javascript enabled to be able to use your site. This might well be fine, but be sure.